# guitar hero 3 freezing at first screen

Tags: guitar-hero, guitar-hero-3

I bought gh3 again today...
Only to find the games freezes at the same screen with the Nintendo logo and the trademark information. I have tried it on a different Wii and the same thing happens. I have already bought 2 copies.

Comment: I highly doubt there's anything we can do for you here. My advice would be to return the games as defective. You've already tried them on 2 Wiis, so I doubt the problem is in your Wii and there's very little you or us can do to the plastic disc that is your game.

Comment: Ok :/ had to be that one tho haha, anyway I'll look into sending them back :) thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh I just remembered the first disc work for a while when I got it then it stopped

Comment: I happen to have Guitar Hero 3 as well, so I checked if there had been any firmware updates that may have broken the game. My EU-versions of the game and the Wii worked perfectly fine.